# Entire canvas become filled?

Tags: gnuplot

I have a 2d graph with the following x and y ranges

```
set xrange [ 460.000 : 600.000 ] noreverse nowriteback
set yrange [ -10.0000 : 55.0000 ] noreverse nowriteback
```

I want to add the following rectangle:

```
set object 1 rectangle from 460,-5 to 600,5 fillcolor rgb "goldenrod" fillstyle solid 0.25 noborder
```

but I'm using the following command:

```
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0, -5 to graph 1, 5 fillcolor rgb "goldenrod" fillstyle solid 0.25 noborder
```

The problem is that the entire canvas become filled when I use this last command...
What is wrong with it?

I'm using the following version

```
G N U P L O T
Version 4.6 patchlevel 5    last modified February 2014
Build System: Linux x86_64
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using a unit prefix like `graph` affects both x and y-value. You must explicitely use `first` for the y-value to fix that:

```
set object 1 rectangle from graph 0, first -5 to graph 1, first 5 \
    fillcolor rgb "goldenrod" fillstyle solid 0.25 noborder
```

Comment: It worked! Now, let me see if I understood: when I write graph 1, 5, for example, gnuplot understands this as graph 0 and graph 5? Thank you very much!

Comment: Yes. From the documentation (section "Coordinates", `help coordinates`): "If the coordinate system for x is not specified, 'first' is used. If the system for y is not specified, the one used
for x is adopted."